# How do I make clap's argument's value_names optional?

Tags: rust, parameter-passing, command-line-interface, clap

I am trying to make a `date` clone from coreutils. The `man` describes that the command `-r` can have different value "types":

```
-r seconds
        Print the date and time represented by seconds, where seconds is the number of seconds since the Epoch
        (00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970; see time(3)), and can be specified in decimal, octal, or hex.

-r filename
        Print the date and time of the last modification of filename.
```

so the the argument could be described as `[-r seconds | filename]`.
How can I achieve the same in clap?

I already tried having mutliple arguments with the same option-name. Also there is the possibility to have multiple `value_names` in an argument. But i did not find anything about that you can make the names optional.

Comment: It doesn't look like clap directly supports having two arguments with the same short name. If you want to use clap you would probably have to accept that it's shown as one argument, something like `-r seconds or filename` (which would IMO be cleaner anyway).

Comment: That does not sound like coreutils date btw -- are you sure you are not looking at a bsd date tool man page?